# Html 2 png using FF engine

Tags: html, browser, server-side, serverside-javascript

I would find some example uses of FireFox engine to generate graphic file (it can be png)  on server site with using browser engine. I would like achive  the same image as if i open this html file in browser and use prinscr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xvfb (virtual frame buffer) to run Firefox in a headless X environment. Do a google search for [virtual frame buffer firefox](http://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+frame+buffer+firefox)

You can do similar things with webkit (The engine behind Chrome and Safari). For example, look for [webkit python qt](http://www.google.com/search?q=webkit+python+qt). There are Qt bindings for other languages too, but the Python ones are by far the best.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible server-side without some heavy scripting. It would also be fairly resource-intensive if you want to do it on demand.

The closest you can get is the serverside `drawWindow()` method on the `<canvas>` tag, but that is Mozilla-only.